# Как добавить объект в другой объект на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, объекты

Есть объект товар:

```
let refrigerator = {
    price: 840,
    count: 1
};
```

и объект корзина:

```
let basket = {

};
```

как сделать функцию добавления товара в корзину, чтобы имя первого объекта было ключом вторго объекта?

Answer (score -1):

```js
let refrigerator = {
  price: 840,
  count: 1
};

let basket = {};

function addToBasket(item) {
  basket = { ...basket,
    ...item
  }
}

addToBasket({refrigerator})

console.log(basket)
```

Answer (score -1):

Через точку тоже есть способ

```
let basket = {

};

basket.refrigerator = {
    price: 840,
    count: 1
};



console.log(basket)
```

Answer (score -2):

Используется [синтаксис расширения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), который позволят соеденить корзину с объектом товаров.

```js
let refrigerator = {
    price: 840,
    count: 1
};

// если добавить при объявлении
let basket = {
  refrigerator // сокращение от refrigerator: refrigerator
};


let foo = {
    price: 200,
    count: 5
};
let bar = {
    price: 100,
    count: 2
};

// если добавит через функцию
add({ foo, bar })

console.log(basket)

function add (goods) {
  return basket = {
    ...basket,
    ...goods
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а что значат три точки в функции?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator